# Nuxt build on locale is extremly slow

Tags: performance, vue.js, build, nuxt.js, eslint

I have an application based on Nuxt. Eslint is also included. When I need to rebuild application it spend about 10 minutes. I dont understand it. Somebody tell me I have a slow laptop. Its params are i5, 8G ram, 500G SSD, Win10.
What could I do to speed up the build?

PS is it possible to disable EsLint for development?

Here is the nuxt.config.js

```js
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: "lurity",
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: "en",
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      {
        name: "viewport",
        content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1",
      },
      { hid: "description", name: "description", content: "" },
      { name: "format-detection", content: "telephone=no" },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" }],
  },
  server: {
    port: process.env.PORT, // default: 3000
    host: process.env.HOST, // default: localhost
  },
  modern: true,
  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css",
    "@/assets/scss/bulma_styled.scss",
    "@/assets/scss/lurity.scss",
  ],
  router: {
    middleware: "auth",
  },
  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    "~/plugins/helpers.js",
    "~/plugins/apiCalls.js",
    "~/plugins/vue-lazyload.client.js",
    { src: "~/plugins/vue-intersect.client.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/gmaps.client.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/google-auth.client.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/google-tag-manager.client.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/debounce.client.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/braintree.client.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/charts.client.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/vuex-persist.client.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~plugins/leaflet.client.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~plugins/nuxt-client-init.client.js", mode: "client" },
    "~/plugins/map-location.js",
        "~/plugins/notify.js"
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module",
    "@nuxtjs/composition-api/module",
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/buefy
    "nuxt-buefy",
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    "@nuxtjs/axios",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy",
    [
      "nuxt-i18n",
      {
        locales: [
          {
            code: "en",
            iso: "en-GB",
            file: "en_locale.js",
          },
          {
            code: "sk",
            iso: "sk-SK",
            file: "sk_locale.js",
          },
          {
            code: "cz",
            iso: "cs-CZ",
            file: "cs_locale.js",
          },
        ],
        defaultLocale: "en",
        strategy: "no_prefix",
        lazy: true,
        vueI18n: {
          silentTranslationWarn: true,
          silentFallbackWarn: true,
        },
        langDir: "locales/",
        // Enable browser language detection to automatically redirect user
        // to their preferred language as they visit your app for the first time
        // Set to false to disable
        detectBrowserLanguage: {
          // If enabled, a cookie is set once a user has been redirected to his
          // preferred language to prevent subsequent redirections
          // Set to false to redirect every time
          useCookie: true,
          // Cookie name
          cookieKey: "i18n_redirected",
          // Set to always redirect to value stored in the cookie, not just once
          alwaysRedirect: false,
          // If no locale for the browsers locale is a match, use this one as a fallback
          fallbackLocale: "en",
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  buefy: { css: false, materialDesignIcons: false, defaultLocale: "sk-SK" },
  proxy: {
    // Simple proxy
    "/api": {
      target:
        process.env.PROXY || (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
          ? "https://portal-api.lurity.com"
          : "https://portaldev-api.lurity.com"),
    },
  },

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    transpile: ["vuex-stores"],
    loaders: {
      scss: {
        sourceMap: true,
        implementation: require("sass"),
        additionalData: `@import "~@/assets/scss/_bulma_variables.scss"; @import "~@/assets/scss/variables.scss";`,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

This is the result of yarn nuxt build --analyze
[image]

Comment: Hi, what do you expect from this bounty? Not sure that anybody could help you more here without additional info.

Comment: Sorry but no. I dont understand the frameworks which are not optimized for development. Is it possible to switch off eslint completelly?

Comment: ESlint will not impact your build time. If you want to totally ditch ESlint (I don't recommend it), you can always remove `@nuxtjs/eslint-module` from your `package.json` and your `nuxt.config.js` file.

Answer (score 4):

You can check your build and spot the bigger chunks, trying to selectively remove them should lead you to the source of the problem.

Try this command: `yarn nuxt build --analyze`

it will show your bundle in browser, if not, http://localhost:8888

More info: [Nuxt Analyze](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/) and [Webpack bundle analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer#options-for-plugin)

Comment: `nuxt build --analyze` should be enough. Also, even if it may improve the performance, it will not directly reduce the build time if the project is big. It's like saying: "yeah, remove 50% of your code and your app will bundle faster". We need more details here from the author here.

Comment: well, I think you need to launch that command with something. Apart from that, you could use the information you get from the command above to remove something you don't really need of in exchange of better performance or even better, you could use a different package for the same task, more suitable for the project. And yes, if 2 project are built with the same structure and one is the half of the size of the other one, it will build faster.

Comment: So I run the command. Result is in the question. What should I do with it?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing really shocking here in terms of configuration (`nuxt.config.js`).
So I guess that it depends on what is running on your machine when you do build. Also, I'm not sure if the build is slower or not in Windows but this could also be a reason.

You could probably ask a friend or share a github link to people with a more beefy hardware configuration to diagnose the build speed.

I do run the following in my rig:

- latest LTS ubuntu (`20.04`)
- 2x 32GB of DDR4 4000MHz Trident Z royal CAS 18
- Ryzen R9 5950x @stock
- 2TB Samsung Pro NVME

And what is mainly helping from my experience, is a good chunk of RAM (amount) + speed to fit with your CPU. Then, it all comes down to the Webpack settings or other build tools related settings IMO.

---

Lastly, without precise numbers, this question is a bit hard to answer.
Another thing, is maybe looking of the actual build and try to figure out what is slow with your own eyes, it will narrow down your problem IMO.

Comment: Slow means it spend 10 minutes.

Comment: @Čamo the last paragraph of my answer is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

10 minutes is a ridiculous amount of time to build.  I don't know why it would be 10 minutes.  But, if you are asking for a way to increase the build speed of Nuxt, you can use Vite!  Just came out, it's amazing for increasing build speed. https://vite.nuxtjs.org/

Comment: This is not production-ready yet and AFAIK it still uses Webpack for the final build (Vite is only used for dev). It may not be THAT ridiculous if the project is big.